# Pre-generated type-safe client libraries for S/4HANA On-premise 2020 is not available

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am going to use pre-generated VDMs for S/4HANA On-premise system (2020) with Cloud SDK 3.35.0. I can find all the services and data models in java doc of cloud sdk for On-premise system.

The odata v2 services are located in the package **com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.onpremise.v2020.datamodel.odata.services**. But I could not find them in Eclipse with Cloud SDK Spring archetype project. Did I miss something?

https://help.sap.com/doc/f8a1835a26b848f69536b34bf46eeb93/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/s4hana/onpremise/v2020/datamodel/odata/services/package-summary.html

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you do not have these service classes on your classpath is that you do not have the corresponding Maven artifact on your dependency tree.

You require the [Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana/s4hana-api-odata-onpremise-2020) `com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana:s4hana-api-odata-onpremise-2020` to access theses classes.

Please note that the Maven archetype `scp-cf-spring` does reference by default Maven dependencies with the OData VDM for **SAP S/4HANA Cloud**.

When interested in using the OData VDM for **SAP S/4HANA (On-Premise)**, the mentioned dependency must be added explicitly. This is explained in the [SAP Cloud SDK documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/getting-started/#adding-dependencies).